# How do you embed Tableau ask data into your project? (such as self service bi or dashboards)

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep, tableau-cloud

i have a project that has dashboard and self service bi embedded
and have converted the self service bi to ask data. The issue is that after converting self service bi to ask data, it data.trusted_ticket returns -1 and error throws datasource not published.
In the postgres db the db_name changes from vertica (where i fetch extract data) to sql_proxy.

How to publish in in the right way that i can access it through the self service bi api call.
what changes should i do the existing api call which returns trusted ticket, site url and site name

Comment: More of  suggestion but republish the new data source on Tableau server ([creating a lens](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/ask_data_lenses.htm) may help) and check that your target_site ID is hitting the right place.